# Converting military to standard time

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I need to display the following Jekyll front-matter in two different formats: military format for a JS library and standard format for display. It seems to be way more complicated than it should be. Any ideas? I'm open to changing the format of the `yaml` as well if there's a better way to specify it.

```
---
layout: event
title: Big Air Trampoline Park Field Trip
start: "13:00"
end: "15:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an include for this, hopefully someone will suggest a better approach:

```
{% assign times = include.param | split: ':' %}
{% assign h = times[0] | modulo:12 %}
{% assign hh = times[0] | modulo:24 %}

{% if h == 0 %}12{% else %}{{h}}{% endif %}:{{times[1]}}
{% if h == hh %}am{% else %}pm{% endif %}
```

I call it like this:

```
{% include display_time.html param=event.start %}
```